# Auto Layout for programmatically added UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a GameViewController. In this GVC im generating a CGRect like this:

```
-(void) generateLevel1 {

    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.gameModel.cards count]; i++) {
        NSInteger value = ((CardModel *)self.gameModel.cards[i]).value;


        CGFloat x = (i % _CARDS_PER_ROW) * 120 + (i % _CARDS_PER_ROW) * 40 + 208;

        CGFloat y = j * 122 + j * 40 + 324;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 125, 125);


        CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPosition:i andValue:value];

        if (!((CardModel *)self.gameModel.cards[i]).outOfPlay) {
            [self.boardView addSubview:cv];


        }
    }
}
```

So i have now my View called boardView, and added a subView called cv.

My Code is written for iPad, and now i want to make an universal App, so i need, that my CGRect is downsized for iPhone 4,5,6,6+.

Whats the best way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to use auto-layout? Do you want to scale the cards up or add padding between them? Do you want to keep the same grid or add more columns and less rows? There are so many options...

Comment: I just want, that it looks equal on all screens. So if i play level1 on iphone, that it looks the same on ipad

Comment: Then just scale it up, the trivial (and not very good) approach being to not use a launch XIB. Really you should use a more appropriate approach in your code so the cards are a proportion of the available screen space...

Comment: but i thought the advantage of is and auto layout is, that i can do programming and auto layout makes the rest for me... seems that this is wrong. is there any other way to give them programmatically constraints or something? or can you show me, how i can set the cards on the screen in proportion of my available screen?

Comment: Use auto layout.  Use the right constraints.  You shouldn't really be dealing with `CGRect`s with auto layout...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

Auto Layout can constrain views to their container, which adapts to different devices and size classes.

You can setup Auto Layout constraints (either programmatically or in Storyboard) for your card view.  This will size the card view for you.  Now, your question really is about laying out cards in a view that Auto Layout has already (proportionally) sized for you.

**The key point is that Auto Layout is determining the frame (size and position) of a view for you.**  Don't try to set or change a view's frame on your own.  Let Auto Layout do its job, and size and position every view for you.

Within the card view, you could add your cards to a `UIStackView` (new in iOS 9), a contained collectionViewController, or some other form of grid control.

If you want to write your app for iOS 9, `UIStackView` is the easiest way to layout the cards.  You won't have to add any constraints for the cards you add, as the stack view can take care of the card spacing for you.  Depending on how simple your card layout is, the stack view could even take the place of the card view.  If you need a grid layout, just use a stack view for each row of cards.

What I'd recommend is to set up these views and their constraints in a storyboard.  (You could do it programmatically, but it sounds like you want to learn how to let Xcode and Auto Layout do the heavy lifting for you.)  Your GameViewController can add the cards to the card view (container), which will layout the cards for you.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use mathematic instead of set the numbers. As the CardView is a subview of CardModel, you can use the CardModel size to calculate the CardView size. For example:

```
width = CardModel.frame.size.width / 4 * 3; //Will get 75% of the superview

height = CardModel.frame.size.height / 5 * 2; //Will et 40% of the CardModel height size

//Will get the center point of the CardModel view
xPosition = CardModel.frame.size.width / 2;
yPosition = CardModel.frame.size.height / 2;

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
```

Now you have an subview with 75% width size, 40% height size and centered in the CardModel. In every dispositive (Ipad, iphone, etc) your subview will always have this percent of size.

Remember that you can use fix size and only calculate the position.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't adapt to size classes.  Adaptive UI uses Storyboard (or trait collection) size classes to determine how to lay itself out.  (The OP can continue to code it using frames, but it's not going to look good across a range of devices, and will likely behave in undesired ways.)

Comment: Storyboard is better, of course. But i gave a programmatically solution, maybe he/she don't want to migrate the class to Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You aren't currently using auto-layout, you're explicitly calculating and settings frames. You should use auto-layout. Specifically, you should create each card with constraints to the cards around it (the spacing between them), to the superview for the cards at the edges of the grid (for the overall grid size) and back to the first card to specify that all the cards have the same width and height. In this way you don't calculate any sizes, you just set the padding around the cards and auto-layout does all of the grid layout for you.